# Create line from Y to Y=0 when Y is stat(count) - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a line from my Y point to Y=0 for each of my data points. My Y axis is "stat(count)", which seems to be creating problems when I add "geom_segment". This works to create my graph:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = X, y = stat(count))) +    
theme_minimal() +   stat_count(geom = "point") +   
ylim(0,4) +   
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,457,50))
```

However, when I add in

```
  geom_segment(aes(xend=X, yend=0))
```

I get the following error:

> "Error: Aesthetics must be valid computed stats. Problematic
>   aesthetic(s): y = stat(count). Did you map your stat in the wrong
>   layer?"

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset such as described in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't understand your data, `X` is continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Wihtout having to use `stat = "count"` in `ggplot2`, you can calculate the count of each object outside of `ggplot2` for example using `count` function from `dplyr` package:

Here, I simulate a X sequence of 10 different numbers with differnt count values:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10,50,replace = TRUE))

df %>% count(x)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
       x     n
   <int> <int>
 1     1     4
 2     2     6
 3     3     2
 4     4    10
 5     5     4
 6     6     1
 7     7     9
 8     8     5
 9     9     5
10    10     4
```

Then, you can pass this count as your `yend` argument into `geom_segment of`ggplot2` as follow:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% count(x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x))+
  geom_point(aes(y = n))+
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, y=0, yend = n))
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

If not, can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset by using this link: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)